# Linker error: access beyond end of merged section

Tags: gcc, linker, fortran, hpc

I've built my code on a machine with gcc 6.3 before. I'm building the same code on another machine with gcc 5.3. I tried using the working oed library from a different location. But still the error persists. I went through suggestions in other questions similar to this on Stackoverflow, but they suggest that the library must be already linked. This is not the case though. 
Oed is a fortran library and the code is in C and C++.

I'm at a loss to think how to figure out this problem. Any help is welcome.

```
/usr/bin/ld: oed__gener_nai_batch.o: access beyond end of merged section (380) 
/usr/bin/ld: oed__gener_nai_batch.o: access beyond end of merged section (586)
/usr/bin/ld: oed__gener_nai_batch.o: access beyond end of merged section (580)
/usr/bin/ld: /home/umunipala/gamess/gamess-kris-simgms/simgms/oed/liboed.a(oed__gener_nai_batch.o)(.debug_info+0x203): reloc against `.debug_str': error 2
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: After what command do you have the error above? How (and on what machine) was oed compiled? As a guess: you cannot move a library compiled on a given machine to another machine as the linked libraries might differ.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two solutions I think.

1. recompile the .c file with your current library settings.
2. export a corresponded version LD library.

The problem is basically caused by the disagreement between .o file and your gcc(compiler).

Comment: is the the compiler? or the linker? you mention GCC as if that answers the question, but GCC is just a compiler driver. The linker is ld, and the compiler is cc1plus. So which is it?

Comment: Hi searchengine27, I am not sure if you really need an answer from me... I am grateful that you pointed out the inaccuracy in my answer, but I don't see what that has to do with solving the problem... I put the compiler here to mean the whole environment that it has when compiling the original file. And usually, it could be just differed by the GCC version from my experience. [ Sorry for the late reply and I would be happy to hear more from you. ]